# NodeJS net socket data completed

Tags: node.js, sockets

I would like use `Net` module for save JSON data on other client. But the data receiver on `client.on('data')` isn't completed.

```
const server = net.createServer(socket => {
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.name = socket.address().address;

  clients.push(socket);

  socket.on('data', data => {
    broadcast(data, socket);
  });

  socket.on('end', () => {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
  });

  function broadcast(message, sender) {
    clients.forEach(client => {
      if (client === sender) return;
      client.write(message);
    });
  }
});
```

Sending my data :

```
client.write(JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription));
```

And my client code :

```
client.on('data', data => {
  alert(data); // return data uncompleted
  alert(typeof data); // return object Buffer

  client.destroy();
});
```

I've try to run `data.toString()`, but i've this error :

`JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string`

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Comment: Simply put: TCP doesn't guarantee that data will be sent (and thus, received) in one packet: it can be split over multiple packets, so could trigger multiple `data` events.

Comment: apart from the data event, can not I wait for all the data to be received ?

Comment: You could use a particular delimiter that signals end-of-data, or use an existing protocol that works with delimited frames (like WebSocket or something).